# Update value in DB every five minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, twitter

I am building a webapp where user have a ranking based on their twitter activity and their activity on my website.

Therefore I'd like to update their rank every five minutes, pulling their latest activity from twitter and update it in my database. I was thinking of using something like this:

```
var minutes = 5, the_interval = minutes * 60 * 1000;
setInterval(function() {
  // my update here
}, the_interval);
```

However, I have several questions about this code:

1. where should I save it to make sure it is run?
2. will it slow my program or is it a problem to pull data out of twitter every five minute? Should I use their streaming API instead?

Note: I am using mongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you create a scheduled task/chron job/etc. (depends on your host OS) to call a separate Node.JS application that performs the specific tasks you want to do periodically and then it would exit when complete. (Or you could use a [`ChildProcess`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) potentially as well).

While Node.JS is async, there's no need, given the description you provided, to perform this work within the same application process that is serving a web application. In fact, as it sounds like "busy work", it would be best handled by a distinct process to avoid impacting directly any of your interactive web users.

Answer (score 0):

The placement shouldn't really matter as Node is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks, I am beginner with node so I am not sure I get everything perfectly :)
If I put this in my app.js file (my main file) it will be updated even if nobody goes on my website?

Comment: As long as it's not inside your web server's callback it'll update on it's own.